# My shortcode content appears at the top of the webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have this code below which adds an extra tab to my user account area. There is a section in the middle where you can add content within the tab. When I enter text it stays in this area, however the shortcode contents appears outside the account box and sits at the top of the page.

Is there anything that I can add to properly implement the shortcode here?

```
 // My Brands tab



add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'my_custom_tab_in_um2', 100 );
    function my_custom_tab_in_um2( $tabs ) {
       $tabs[800]['mybrands']['icon'] = 'um-icon-android-star';
       $tabs[800]['mybrands']['title'] = 'My Favourite Brands';
       $tabs[800]['mybrands']['custom'] = true;
            $tabs[800]['mybrands']['show_button'] = false;

   return $tabs;
}


add_action('um_account_tab__mybrands', 'um_account_tab__mybrands');
function um_account_tab__mybrands( $info ) {
   global $ultimatemember;
   extract( $info );

   $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('mybrands');
   if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
}

add_filter('um_account_content_hook_mybrands', 'um_account_content_hook_mybrands');
function um_account_content_hook_mybrands( $output ){
   ob_start();
   ?>

   <div class="um-field">


page or shortcode or content here.
      [my_lotteries]



   </div>      

   <?php

   $output .= ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $output;
}
```

The section in question

```
page or shortcode or content here.
      [my_lotteries]
```

Comment: I think you're returning the shortcode and not echoing it.

Comment: post the `my_lotteries` shortcode callback function. You are probably echoing the output in the callback method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[my_lotteries]' ); ?>`

Comment: if the shortcode content is being displayed at the top of the page it means that the OP has an issue in how the shortcode is being created. That is output is being echoed instead of returned. Applying `do_shortcode` will not make a difference in this case until the shortcode callback function is fixed

Comment: @CornelRaiu where does one begin with this?

Comment: The above by Joel did work o keep it in place within my tab, but the images that are within this shortcode take forever to load for some reason.

Comment: Can you open the dev tools and run a scan?

Comment: Since it's doing what you want, but not exactly what you want, open another question and link it here, and we can troubleshoot what exactly is making it run so slowly. ;)